# A char array containing strings, and a pointer pointing at that array. How do I loop through it? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, char

```
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;

void main() {
    char MONTH_0[] = "January";
    char MONTH_1[] = "February";
    char MONTH_2[] = "March";
    char MONTH_3[] = "April";

    char* pMonth[] = {MONTH_0,MONTH_1,MONTH_2,MONTH_3};

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        cout << *pMonth;
        pMonth[i];
    }
}
```

Hey everyone, I'm new to coding in C++ and I got a simple assignment to print all the year months in order. I'm looking for a neat way of doing it so I came up with a char array containing all the months.
I currently been able to print "January" without any problem, but I've tried pMonth++ or pMonth[i] but nothing increments the pointer at the next char array. Thanks for your time.
**We are not allowed to use string library!**

Comment: `pMonth[i]` is the correct way. As seems very common, you're asking about code but you haven't posted the code that isn't working! Why not?

Comment: Also there are 12 months `for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {`

Comment: Apart from your loop accessing the array out of bounds (you only have 4 elements, not 11), if you change `cout << *pMonth;` to `cout << pMonth[i];` it should do what you want, doesn't it? The standalone `pMonth[i];` doesn't do anything

Comment: This is the the code that isn't working for some odd reason. It keeps printing "January January January January" in the console.

Comment: @Joints Of course, but you said `I tried pMonth[i]`. Show that code, because that's how you should do it.

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks, you've solved it!

Comment: Unless you plan to be modifying these month names, there's no need to store them all in separate char arrays and then build the array.  A simple array of string literals will suffice: `const char* pMonth[12] = {  "January", "February", /* ... */ "December" };`

Comment: @Joints I've confused, you said 'I tried pMonth[i]' then you are shown code using 'pMonth[i]' and it fixes the problem? What exactly had you written when you tried 'pMonth[i]'?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    char MONTH_0[] = "January";
    char MONTH_1[] = "February";
    char MONTH_2[] = "March";
    char MONTH_3[] = "April";

    char *pMonth[] = {MONTH_0,MONTH_1,MONTH_2,MONTH_3};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(pMonth) / sizeof(pMonth[0]); i++)
        std::cout << pMonth[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Or Using [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

```
#include <array>
// ...

std::array<std::string, 4> arr = { "January", "February", "March", "April"};
for (const auto& i: arr)
    std::cout << "Month: " << i << std::endl;
```